# Possible to import classes from a module, use them as private base classes, but not re-export?

Tags: c++, module, c++20

I'm trying to make sure I understand modules correctly with some toy examples. One use case that I could see being relevant would be implementation-hiding by having base classes that aren't part of the exported portion of a module.

Using Visual Studio 16.11.2, the following code behaves as I would expect:

PublicModule.ixx:

```
export module PublicModule;

class PrivateImpl
{
protected:
  int x = 7;
};

export class PublicClass : private PrivateImpl
{
public:
  int getX() const { return x; }
};
```

main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>

import PublicModule;

int main()
{
  PublicClass pc;
  std::cout << pc.getX() << '\n'; // Prints 7

  // PrivateImpl pi; // This doesn't compile because PrivateImpl wasn't exported from PublicModule
}
```

However, if I try to move the class `PrivateImpl` into its own module as follows:

PrivateModule.ixx:

```
export module PrivateModule;

export class PrivateImpl
{
protected:
  int x = 7;
};
```

PublicModule.ixx:

```
export module PublicModule;

import PrivateModule;

export class PublicClass : private PrivateImpl
{
public:
    int getX() const { return x;  }
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>

import PublicModule;

int main()
{
  PublicClass pc;
  std::cout << pc.getX() << '\n'; // Prints 7

  PrivateImpl pi; // This compiles, even though main.cpp doesn't import anything 
                  // that (appears to) export  PrivateImpl
}
```

What I thought would happen is that `import PrivateModule;` would import `PrivateImpl` from the private module, but *not* re-export it because I didn't say `export import PrivateModule;`. And I wouldn't think that exporting `PublicClass` by itself would be enough to export its private base, because the first version works as I expected.

Am I misunderstanding how module exports work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is **correct** for both examples: this is evidently a compiler bug.  Name lookup doesn’t consider whether a name is *used* in some other translation unit.